Why does ASP.NET Core 9 strip out importmap?
I have seen this on a newly-generated ASP.NET Core 9 app and in an app I upgraded to .NET 9 from .NET 8.
This is in Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml:
   <script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
            "axios": "/js/axios.min.js",
            "axios-retry": "/js/axios-retry.js",
            "is-retry-allowed": "/js/is-retry-allowed.js"
        }
      }
   </script>

and it gets stripped out. When I look at the devtools/sources tab in Chrome, it's there for the .NET 8 app, but not for the .NET 9 app.
How do I stop .NET 9 from doing that?
Edit: I found that the ScriptTagHelper class is the culprit.
If I add the following to _ViewImports.cshtml the importmap is not stripped out:
@removeTagHelper Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.ScriptTagHelper, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

I'm guessing I don't want the ScriptTagHelper class permanently disabled (or do I?). Is there a way to tell it "leave my importmap alone"?

After checking the source code, you are missing asp-importmap when using importmap.
Source code links:
private const string ImportMapAttributeName = "asp-importmap";
If we are missing asp-importmap attribute, we will get null exception in below code. That's why the script content not render in broswer.
var importMap = ImportMap ?? ViewContext.HttpContext.GetEndpoint()?.Metadata.GetMetadata();
Here is the soultion
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@{
    var data = new ImportMapDefinition(
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "axios", "/js/axios.min.js" },
            { "axios-retry", "/js/axios-retry.js" },
            { "is-retry-allowed", "/js/is-retry-allowed.js" },
        },null,null);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - _79279047_1</title>
    <script type="importmap" asp-importmap="@data"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/_79279047_1.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">_79279047_1</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2024 - _79279047_1 - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
   

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>

Test Result


Thanks for that, I experienced the same issue. The "documentation" on that seems to be wrong. From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/80-90?view=aspnetcore-9.0&tabs=visual-studio#replace-usestaticfiles-with-mapstaticassets:
"In MVC & Razor pages apps, add  to the head of the main layout file, which is updated by the Import Map Tag Helper."

@Jason Pan: Thanks for that. I did read in the docs that ImportMapDefinition is expensive to create. Does that apply to a simple case such as above? Or does that mean when it's used in Blazor and has to dynamically create the map?

Creating the ImportMapDefintion itself is as cheap as it can get. What they probably mean is that automatically creating the instance from a set of assets that are resolved from the application resources is quite expensive.

So since I came here looking for a reason why MapStaticAssets() doesn't create an import map and why static import maps are removed from the rendered HTML, I decided to submit an answer for that as well.
After digging a while, I found out that the template seems to be just broken, and there is an issue tracking that.
Instead
app.MapControllerRoute(
  name: "default",
  pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
).WithStaticAssets();

mapping the static assets like
app.MapControllers()
   .WithStaticAssets();
app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();

fixes the issue and an import map will be generated from the JavaScript assets.

I'll give that a spin when I next get chance.
